# Excel FROM syntax error

Tags: excel, syntax

I have a syntax error in from clause and cant find it. Any help is appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Connect(strVar As String)
Dim strEmps As String, strPath As String
  strEmps = "SELECT tblStudents.fldStudentNo, tblStudents.fldFirstName, tblStudents.fldLastName, tblStudents.fldTelephone, tblDepartments.fldDepartmentName, tblClasses.fldClassDate, tblClasses.fldClassName "
  strEmps = strEmps & "FROM (tblDepartments INNER JOIN ON tblDepartments.[fldDepartmentNo] = tblStudents.[fldDeptNo]) INNER JOIN (tblClasses INNER JOIN tblStudentsAndClasses ON tblClasses.[fldClassNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldClassNo]) ON tblStudents.[fldStudentNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldStudentNo] "
  strEmps = strEmps & "WHERE fldClassName = '" & strVar & "' ORDER BY fldLastName "
  strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & cstrPath
  Set connEmp = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rstEmps = New ADODB.Recordset
  connEmp.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & strPath & "'"
  rstEmps.Open strEmps, connEmp, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
  Call DisplayData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tara, you have missing table in the INNER JOIN:

Check this line of code, where **tblStudents** was missing in the INNER JOIN

Your Code:

```
strEmps = strEmps & "FROM (tblDepartments INNER JOIN ON tblDepartments.[fldDepartmentNo] = tblStudents.[fldDeptNo]) INNER JOIN (tblClasses INNER JOIN tblStudentsAndClasses ON tblClasses.[fldClassNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldClassNo]) ON tblStudents.[fldStudentNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldStudentNo] "
```

Instead use this:

```
strEmps = strEmps & "FROM (tblDepartments INNER JOIN tblStudents ON tblDepartments.[fldDepartmentNo] = tblStudents.[fldDeptNo]) INNER JOIN (tblClasses INNER JOIN tblStudentsAndClasses ON tblClasses.[fldClassNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldClassNo]) ON tblStudents.[fldStudentNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldStudentNo] "
```